# Can we use 'as' in the past perfect?

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

I want to know whether this sentence is correct:

**She came as I had done my homework**

According to [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/amp/british-grammar/as-when-or-while), **as** is used to connect two events that happen at the same time. What I doubt is, the connection between past simple and past perfect with **as**. I'm not sure why I think it's incorrect, but it just sounds wrong since I've never seen using **as** in past perfect.

By the way, I make up the sentence. I just want to know if **as** can be used together with past perfect and past simple.

Comment: _She came as I was finishing my homework_ (two events at the same time). But you could say _She came after I had done my homework_ (while you were in the state of 'having done' it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't (with an exception I discuss below).

You can say: "She got home as I was doing my homework."  You can also possibly say: "She got home as I did my homework," although this second version doesn't sound as idiomatic as the first in spoken English.

However, if you are using "as" to mean "since" (i.e. implying a causal link), you can use the  present or past perfect:

> I got an A on my exam, as I had studied very hard for it.